# Pass variable to execution directive without executing the variable content

Tags: shell-script, shell, bash-expansion

I've created a helper function to display a message into the current pane:

```
function current_pane_id {
  echo "$(tmux display -p '#{pane_id}')"
}


function display_message {
  message="$1"
  "$(tmux display-message -p -t"$(current_pane_id)" "'$message'")"
}
```

that is used like this:

```
display_message "turned display on"
```

The problem is that rather then pass the content of `$message` to to the command, it keeps trying to execute the content of `$message`, and it doesn't seem to matter how I try to quote it, it keeps executing it.

How do I pass the content of the variable to the command without having bash execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is caused by the unnecessary `$(...)`.

```
function display_message {
  message="$1"
  tmux display-message -p -t"$(pane_id)" "'$message'"
}
```

Comment: `$pane_id` is a function, I'll update the OP, should have made that clearer

Comment: ... likewise in the `current_pane_id` function.